# Scrapy cannot run crawl

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I was running Scrapy on a very simple example code(shown below, from a tutorial website ) to test if it is set up correctly.

The code I copied:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class RedditbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redditbot'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

When I ran the following command

```
scrapy crawl redditbot
```

the following errors happened

[image: The errors]

I am not sure what's happening and seeking for help on setting up scrapy correctly.

Comment: Do not post code screenshots instead copy paste the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

See:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143

And:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3325

And, finally:

https://github.com/twisted/twisted/pull/966

Long story short, this is a bug with Twisted for Python 3.7--not Scrapy at all. Scrapy is more of a framework than a stand-alone Python module. Scrapy itself imports a ton of modules that it uses--one of those being Twisted. So, bugs can happen with any number of modules it uses.

You are running Python 3.7 which currently is the newest of the new. Not all modules will support Python 3.7 perfectly right away; hence this is the case with Twisted trying to use the new `async` keyword that is brand new to Python 3.7. See:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html

I would recommend installing Python 3.6 for now; then `pip` or `pipenv` will only install the versions of modules that are more stable with Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Right now scrapy doesn't support Python 3.7 temporarily because `async` keyword is reserved in python 3.7 and scrapy's dependancy `twisted` has not yet resolved this issue.

See scrapy issue regarding this: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143

Current fix for this is to install Twisted branch that has this fix:

> you can install the branch with `pip install git+https://github.com/lopuhin/twisted.git@9384-remove-async-param`

Answer (score 1):

another solution from the `scrapy` side would be to disable the extension causing the error which is the `scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole` extension.

Just update the following lines in `settings.py`:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
}
```

It is very likely that you are not going to use telnet for your spider, so this shouldn't complicate anything on your project.